# Error repairing setup created in WiX 3.8

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.6, wix3.7

I have created a Web Server setup in WiX (3.8), It gets installed correctly, but when i Repair it, I get an error 'Fatal error during Installation' and the process is rolled back. below is what i see in logs

```
MSI (s) (F8:C4) [12:39:26:183]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=WriteIIS7ConfigChanges,ActionType=11265,Source=BinaryData,Target=**********,CustomActionData=**********)
MSI (s) (F8:F8) [12:39:26:188]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI7B14.tmp, Entrypoint: WriteIIS7ConfigChanges
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x80070002: Site not found for create application
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x80070002: Failed to configure IIS application.
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x80070002: WriteIIS7ConfigChanges Failed.
CustomAction WriteIIS7ConfigChanges returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 12:39:26: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
```

Am i missing out something. Any help is appreciated, Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2):

If it's a repair and the site name is missing, chances are that it was entered in a UI dialog in the original install. In a repair there is no UI to re-enter the site name and properties aren't automatically saved. It may be trying to configure a site with no name. The best way to deal with this type of thing in general is to use the WiX remember property pattern on the site name so that it is preserved and is available for a repair. I can't tell if that would be a good thing in this particular case because I don't know if writing the config changes again on top of the existing config changes will work or be handled correctly by the code.  A verbose log of the original install should tell you what property names are being used for site names etc.

If you think it's unlikely that the IIS config changes will break and that they won't need repair, you could consider adding "Not Installed" to the condition on the CA so that a repair won't call it.